# Instantiate a static abstract class through reflections

Tags: java, android, reflection

```
public class FingerprintManager {

     * @hide
     */
   // this class is hidden 
    public static abstract class EnrollmentCallback {

        public void onEnrollmentError(int errMsgId, CharSequence errString) { }


        public void onEnrollmentHelp(int helpMsgId, CharSequence helpString) { }


        public void onEnrollmentProgress(int remaining) { }
    };
}
```

EnrollmentCallback  class is hidden.Is there a way to instantiate EnrollmentCallback class through reflection which is equivalent to :

```
EnrollmentCallback callbackObject = new EnrollmentCallback ()
{
        public void onEnrollmentError(int errMsgId, CharSequence errString) { }


        public void onEnrollmentHelp(int helpMsgId, CharSequence helpString) { }


        public void onEnrollmentProgress(int remaining) { }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

No. It might be possible to do that with a byte-code manipulation library (like [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/)), but it's not possible to instantiate an `abstract` class without extending it and implementing any missing (`abstract`) methods. And you can't do that with Java reflection.